# i can't generate scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
C:\Sites\demo_app>rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
C:/Sites/demo_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': undefined metho
d `groups' for Rails:Module (NoMethodError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9
/lib/rails/commands.rb:15:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9
/lib/rails/commands.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `application.rb` file.

Check for the following lines:

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
end
```

they should be replaced with

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460870/351901) by NeoRiddler