# Can't generate scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I try to use [this tutorial](http://russian.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec:planning_the_application), but have some problems with scaffold generation code.

application.rb

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler) 
#if defined?(Bundler) 
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
#end
```

Take solution from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822904/undefined-method-groups-for-railsmodule/8460870#8460870), but not well for this problem.

Log:

```
C:\Users\Evgeny\Rails_projects\demo_app>rails generate scaffold User name:string
 email:string
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/ra
iltie/configuration.rb:77:in `method_missing': undefined method `assets' for #<R
ails::Application::Configuration:0x3a03248> (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Users/Evgeny/Rails_projects/demo_app/config/application.rb:55:in
 `<class:Application>'
        from C:/Users/Evgeny/Rails_projects/demo_app/config/application.rb:14:in
 `<module:DemoApp>'
        from C:/Users/Evgeny/Rails_projects/demo_app/config/application.rb:13:in
 `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9
/lib/rails/commands.rb:15:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9
/lib/rails/commands.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Config app:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.9'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.3'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something with assets. I think you need to upgrade your rails to 3.1 at least. 3.2.3 is better.

Try to create new project with last version of rails 3.2.3.

or try this solution http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1 or last chapter of tutorial book http://russian.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-3-1#top .

One more solution without upgrading, but I'm not sure. In your config/application.rb try to find config.assets.enabled and set it to false.

Answer (score 1):

Rails asset pipeline isn't available until Rails 3.1 and later.  I'm guessing that on line 55 of C:/Users/Evgeny/Rails_projects/demo_app/config/application.rb, you have a config.assets line which is causing the issue.  Either remove that line or upgrade to Rails 3.1 or 3.2